# GWT css resources obfuscation error

Tags: css, gwt

I have this style in my uibinder:

```
<ui:style type="com.mycompany.MyApp.MyStyle">
      .something {
             width: 50em;
       }

    div.dm {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50em;
    }

     .test-name {
        margin: 10px 10px;
    }       
</ui:style>
```

This is the interface for the resource:

```
    interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
        @ClassName("something ")  //This doesn't work either
        String somethingClass();
//        String something(); //This works!
        @ClassName("div.dm")
        String divClass();
        @ClassName("test-name")
        String testNameClass();
      }
```

But then i get this error:

```
  [ERROR] div.dm: Fix by adding .something{}
  [ERROR] div.dm: Fix by adding .div.dm{}
  [ERROR] test-name: Fix by adding .test-name{}
  [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding
```

Anybody have any idea? I am using GWT 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

(Deleted previous answer, didn't make sense in this context).

It looks like this is a bug (or intended?). In the GWT issue tracker are several reports somewhat related: [Capitalized classnames used in @ClassName within  doesn't work](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5445) and [Non-Java method safe characters in inline  class names doesn't work](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4052) the latter has state fixed, but also has a comment remarking to make ClassName work. This comment was before the fixed issue, so it's not clear if it was intended to be fixed, or it was fixed, but doesn't work.

ClassName only seems to work in the following combination:

```
@ClassName("test-name")
String testName()
```

and in css:

```
.test-name {
}
```

The way to go seems to be use the same name in method/ui:style or use the dash/camelcase combination.

Answer (score 1):

In your `div.dm` selector, the class name is `dm`, so `@ClassName("dm")`.

I unfortunately don't understand about the `test-name`; let's hope it's a side-effect of the first error ;-)